# Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object in codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Auth::$facebook

Filename: controllers/auth.php

Line Number: 39

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object
>   in
>   /home/xyz/public_html/domainname.com/sc/application/controllers/auth.php
>   on line 39

and my controller code is

```
class Auth extends CI_CONTROLLER {
    private $uid;

    private $access_token;

    public function __constract(){

    parent::__constract();
    $this->load->library("facebook",array(
        "appId"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "secret"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ));

    $this->uid= $this->facebook->getUserLogin();
    $this->access_token= $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $this->facebook->getAccessToken($this->getAccessToken());
}

public function index(){

        if($this->uid){

            try{

                $me = $this->facebook->api("/me");

                print_r($me);

            }catch( FacebookApiException $e){

                print_r($e);

                $this->uid = NULL;

            }

        }else{
        die("<script>top.location='".$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(

                "scope"=>"email",

                "redirect_Url"=>site_url("auth")

            ))."'<script>");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: public function __constract() 
Shouldn't it be construct() ?

Comment: dear I am totally new and  I do not know What can I do..... please help me this is my first project

Comment: construct() is correct !!

Comment: Yes Its not working when I echo in public function __constract()

Comment: I use public function constract() but its not working

Answer (score 1):

It should be `construct` not `constract` -

```
public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("facebook",array(
        "appId"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "secret"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ));
    $this->uid= $this->facebook->getUserLogin();
    $this->access_token= $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $this->facebook->getAccessToken($this->getAccessToken());
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getUserLogin() in /home/xyz/public_html/mydomin.com/sc/application/controllers/auth.php on line 14

Comment: Have you initialize the facebook class?

Comment: sorry for late and yes I initialize the facebook class

Comment: Does the function getUserLogin()  exist in the Facebook class?

Comment: where did you initialized it??

Comment: Dear sgt thanks facebook class is already in sdk and in this no any function like  getUserLogin()

Comment: in /sc/application/libraries/facebook

Comment: You need to have that object in `$this->facebook`.

Comment: but getUserLogin object is not in this classs